# Android SQLite Exception for some Devices / Localities

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a Live Android App in the PlayStore; it reads data from a SQLite and displays end the front end. It works fine on devices of family and friends in the UK. However, the app won't launch for one device in India and one device in Pakistan.

Here is the database path definition in the SQLiteOpenHelper class:

```
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.deenbook.arabixlite/databases/";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ATDB3";
```

Here is the Stack Trace I have acquired using the Play Console:

SQLiteException
in Database.getProps

Stack Trace:

[image: Stack Trace]

Here is my database class:

```
    package com.deenbook.arabixlite;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.deenbook.arabixlite/databases/";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ATDB3";

    private static SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    private static Context context= null;

    private static String LANGUAGE;

    public Database(Context context, String source, boolean override, String lang) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
        this.LANGUAGE= lang;

        try {
            createDataBase(source, override);
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
    }


    public void createDataBase(String source, boolean override) throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(override)
        {
            copyDataBase();
            return;
        }
        if(dbExist)
        {
        }
        else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("DBH Error copying database: "+source);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean executeSQLBatch(ArrayList<String> sql)
    {
        boolean ok= true;
        for(int i=0; i<sql.size(); i++)
        {
            if(executeSQL(sql.get(i))==false)
            {
                ok= false;
            }
        }

        return ok;
    }

    public boolean executeSQL(String sql) {
        boolean ok= true;
        try {

            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

            db.execSQL(sql);

            db.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            ok= false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return ok;
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // database does't exist yet.
        }

        if (checkDB != null) {

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public static void openDataBase(String source) throws SQLException {

        String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion > newVersion)
        {
            try{
                copyDataBase();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String[]> getProps()
    {
        ArrayList<String[]> data= new ArrayList<String[]>();

        String sql= "Select * from ARABIX_PROPS";

        try {
            openDataBase("getProps");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(sql, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String KEY= cursor.getString(0);
                String VALUE= cursor.getString(1);

                String[] kvp= new String[]{KEY, VALUE};

                data.add(kvp);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        myDataBase.close();


        return data;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

- both phones that have had this error are on Android 9
- I just don't understand why it work on some devices and not on others..?

Please help..!!

Comment: Put the full log and stack trace in the question.

Comment: OhhhThatVarun - that is all the information I have. I don't have the issue on my own device. Also, the Stack Trace I have included above, is only available as an image.

Comment: Well, we need more than that. And what line is 263? If it's a new app then why you are not using RoomDB?

Comment: OhhhThatVarun - line 263 is a line in the getProps method. It is: Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(sql, null);     Also, thanks for suggesting RoomDB - I must admit, I had never heard of it before now...